# ArSession_update take a lot of time

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

In my application, without ARCore, it shows over 60 fps. But after push ARCore function in it, frame rate goes down almost 30 fps.

So, as far I understand AR core work only in 30 fps, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

[ARCore 1.11](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) (that was released on 05th August 2019) targets frame rate **`60fps`** on supported devices.

From now, you can, of course, use new camera config filters to target **`30fps`** on all ARCore smartphones:

```
// Set target camera capture frame rate filter

CameraConfigFilter()

setTargetFps(EnumSet<CameraConfig.TargetFps> frameRates)
```

and:

```
// Set depth sensor usage filter

CameraConfigFilter()

setDepthSensorUsage(EnumSet<CameraConfig.DepthSensorUsage> depthSensorUsageFilters)
```